# How can I pass more parameters with AJAX

Tags: ajax

I have the following:

```
$('#TopicDescription').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/adminQuestions/GetSubTopics",
                data: $('#TopicDescription').val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#SubTopicDescription').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

This works good but I would like to pass another parameter. Can someone explain how I can do this. Also in the GetSubTopics method will the parameter passed be referenced by the word "data" and is there a connection between data: and the .html(data).

Sorry if my question is confusing.

Beverly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass an object in data:

```
data: {
    foo : 10,
    bar : 42
}
```

Comment: okay I think I understand. So when I want to access the information can I do it like this: public string GetSubTopics(int foo, int bar)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/adminQuestions/GetSubTopics",
    data: { v1: $('#element1').val(),
            v2: $('#element2').val(),
            v3: $('#element3').val()
        },
    success: function(msg) {
        // do something with msg
    }
});
```

> Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not
>   already a string. It's appended to the
>   url for GET-requests. See processData
>   option to prevent this automatic
>   processing. Object must be Key/Value
>   pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery
>   serializes multiple values with same
>   key based on the value of the
>   traditional setting (described below).

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to further explain to me.

Comment: @Beverly... sorry? I don't know how to explain it very well. I updated my response with documentation from the jQuery site.